# There's an issue with the navbar; it doesn't expand when clicked on mobile

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css, navbar

I need someone to help me. I have this issue with my navbar. For some reason, on small screens, I can't get it to work, and the menu doesn't expand when I click on the icon.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };
  return (
    <nav className="bg-white shadow-xl relative">
      <div className="max-w-6xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-2">
        <Link
          href="/dashboard"
          className="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse"
        >
          <Image src="/logo.svg" alt="logo" width={120} height={45} />
          <span className="text-lg text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800">
            Mi Cuenta
          </span>
        </Link>
        <div className="hidden w-full lg:block lg:w-auto">
          <ul className="font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white  ">
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/perfil"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
                aria-current="page"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/user-group-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Perfil
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/historial"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/shopping-cart-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Historial
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/contacto"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/comments-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Contacto
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/terms_cond.pdf"
                target="_blank"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/file-contract-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={10}
                  height={10}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Términos y Condiciones
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/salir"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/right-from-bracket-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Salir
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
        <button
          className="menu-button inline-flex items-center p-2 justify-center text-4xl text-[#046cb3] md:hidden"
          onClick={toggleMenu()}
          aria-label={isMenuOpen ? "Cerrar menú" : "Abrir menú"}
        > 
          {isMenuOpen ? "✖" : "☰"}
        </button>
        {isMenuOpen && (
          <div className="lg:hidden font-semibold bg-slate-200 w-screen h-screen flex flex-col text-center" style={{ zIndex: 999, position: 'fixed'}} >
            <Link
              href="/auth/register"
              className="block text-primary text-2xl hover:text-blue-200 m-10"
            >
              Registrarse
            </Link>
            <Link
              href="/auth/login"
              className="block text-primary text-2xl hover:text-blue-200 m-10"
            >
              Iniciar Sesión
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I tried other navbars that I used on previous sites, but they're not working either. I started to think it might be an issue with the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Remane `toggleMenu` to `ToggleMenu`

```
  const ToggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };
```

Next, change how you call the function on the button `onClick={toggleMenu()}` to `onClick={ToggleMenu}`

Here's the full code below:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const ToggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };
  return (
    <nav className="bg-white shadow-xl relative">
      <div className="max-w-6xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-2">
        <Link
          href="/dashboard"
          className="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse"
        >
          <Image src="/logo.svg" alt="logo" width={120} height={45} />
          <span className="text-lg text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800">
            Mi Cuenta
          </span>
        </Link>
        <div className="hidden w-full lg:block lg:w-auto">
          <ul className="font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white  ">
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/perfil"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
                aria-current="page"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/user-group-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Perfil
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/historial"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/shopping-cart-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Historial
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/contacto"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/comments-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Contacto
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/terms_cond.pdf"
                target="_blank"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/file-contract-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={10}
                  height={10}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Términos y Condiciones
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/dashboard/salir"
                className="flex text-sm text-[#00478a] font-bold hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/right-from-bracket-solid.svg"
                  alt="perfil"
                  width={14}
                  height={14}
                  className="mr-2"
                />
                Salir
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button
          className="menu-button inline-flex items-center p-2 justify-center text-4xl text-[#046cb3] md:hidden"
          onClick={ToggleMenu}
          aria-label={isMenuOpen ? "Cerrar menú" : "Abrir menú"}
        >
          {isMenuOpen ? "✖️" : "☰"}
        </button>
        {isMenuOpen && (
          <div
            className="lg:hidden font-semibold bg-slate-200 w-screen h-screen flex flex-col text-center"
            style={{ zIndex: 999, position: "fixed" }}
          >
            <Link
              href="/auth/register"
              className="block text-primary text-2xl hover:text-blue-200 m-10"
            >
              Registrarse
            </Link>
            <Link
              href="/auth/login"
              className="block text-primary text-2xl hover:text-blue-200 m-10"
            >
              Iniciar Sesión
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```